# keep getting error messages

Tags: drive, convert

im new as hell to this so forgive me. i keep getting error messages when i try and convert .iso to .img. says no such file or directory. i know once i get the converted file i have to do a bunch of stuff. im just trying to get a bootable usb drive, and last time i did this it seemed like it was much much easier. what am i doing wrong?

os x 10.9.1 2g intel core duo/ 2g 1067MHz ddr3

Comment: post the command did you had tried?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then run

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Use this program, it will set up everything; you have to do is locate and pick your .iso file and choose the USB drive.